# xslt apply 2 templates with different modes, on the same element  while preserving order defined in xml

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an xml file with items. I want to output the list of items depending on the view attribute and preserve the order of the elements. For this purpose I have to xsl:templates with different modes. The problem is that I can't preserve the same order as in xml.
The xml is following:

```
   <item />
   <item view="new" />
   <item />
   <item view="new" />
```

the templates are:

```
<xsl:template match="item" mode="standart">
    <div class="standart_item"></div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="item" mode="new">
    <div class="new_item"></div>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I apply different templates to preserve the order, the same as in xml?

```
<div class="standart_item"></div>
<div class="new_item"></div>
<div class="standart_item"></div>
<div class="new_item"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different modes doesn't seem to be the right tool for the result you're trying to achieve. I suggest to distinguish the templates by predicates:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <div class="standard_item"></div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[@view='new']">
  <div class="new_item"></div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have to match the items again within the different templates, that's why I have to use mode

Comment: In this case you could also use a single template matching all items and distinguish them with `xsl:choose` for example. If that's not possible either, you should elaborate a bit more about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to go with xsl:choose

Comment: @tylik: It is very probable it wouldn't be necessary to use `xsl:choose`. If you explain well the problem (providing enogh data), then many people will be able to give ellegan solutions.